# add function received by ajax to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to receive some mixed objects by ajax json and put them into a Global_obj
I can't use $.extend() because some items are javascript functions.

Someone know another (better) way to do this?

```
<?php
$ajax_response = [
    "Obj_1" => [
        "key1_1" => "function(){console.log('ok key1_1')}",
        "key1_2" => "<div>Something key1_2</div>"
    ],
    "Obj_2" => [
        "key2_1" => "function(){console.log('ok key2_1')}",
        "key2_2" => "<div>Something key2_2</div>"
    ]   
];
```

?>

```
<script>

var Global_obj = {};

var ajax_response = <?php echo json_encode($ajax_response); ?>;

$.each(ajax_response,function(key){

    Global_obj[key] = {};

    $.each(this,function(subkey){
        if(this.indexOf('function') > -1){
            Global_obj[key][subkey] = eval( '('+this+ ')' );
        }else{
            Global_obj[key][subkey] = ''+this;
        }
    });
});

Global_obj.Obj_1.key1_1(); // show "ok key1_1"
```

EDITED: I have edited mi old question because marked as duplicate

So the edited question is:
Someone know another (better) way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What is      ''+this     supposed to do?

Comment: aaa sorry for my english without '' (i don't know why) i get an array string so each character is one item of them. So if i add ' '+this ... become a normal string

Comment: Use `eval('(' + this + ')')` instead.

Comment: [SOLVED] @ Felix Kling ... Thank's a lot ... whith eval('(' + this + ')') working good !

Comment: Then if you have a "new question" then ["Ask a new Question"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead. This is not a discussion thread, You just ask new questions. But please don't ask exactly the same thing, since you were afterall pointed to a duplicate from which you should have learned something.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. The  next time will not happen.